# Lua userdata variable communication with C++

Tags: c++, lua

I have a program where users can create Frames using Lua command such as:

```
frm=Frame.new()
```

the above-mentioned command shows a frame to the user. Behind the scenes the C++ wrapper is as follows:

```
Frame* Frame_new(lua_State* L)
{
   int nargs=lua_gettop(L);
   Frame* wb=0;
   if(nargs==0){
       //Omitted
       wb=mainfrm->GetFrame();
       lua_pushlightuserdata(L,(void*)(wb));
       int key=luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
       wb->SetLuaRegistryKey(key);
   }

   return wb;
}
```

Since the frame is shown to the user, the user can close the frame by just clicking on the close button provided by the operating system. This generates a close event and it is handled as follows:

```
void Frm::OnClose(wxCloseEvent& evt)
{
    //Omitted for brevity
    int LuaRegistryKey=GetFrame()->GetLuaRegistryKey();
    lua_rawgeti(glbLuaState,LUA_REGISTRYINDEX,LuaRegistryKey);//userdata
    Frame* wb1=(Frame*)lua_touserdata(glbLuaState,-1); //userdata
    lua_pop(glbLuaState,1); //
    lua_getglobal(glbLuaState,"_G"); //table
    lua_pushnil(glbLuaState); //table key
    while (lua_next(glbLuaState,-2)) {//table key value
      const char* name = lua_tostring(glbLuaState,-2);//table
      if(lua_type(glbLuaState,-1)==LUA_TUSERDATA){
         Frame* wb2=(Frame*)lua_touserdata(glbLuaState,-1);
         if(wb2==m_Frame){ //this part doesnt work
             lua_pushnumber(glbLuaState,0);
             lua_setglobal(glbLuaState,name);
             lua_pop(glbLuaState,1);
             break;
         }
     }
     lua_pop(glbLuaState,1); //table key
   } //table
   lua_pop(glbLuaState,1); //
   if(m_Frame==wb1) {delete m_Frame; m_Frame=0; wb1=0;}
   if(wb1) {delete wb1; wb1=0;}
   luaL_unref(glbLuaState,LUA_REGISTRYINDEX,LuaRegistryKey );
}
```

Now the goal is when user closes the frame the variable created by `frm=Frame.new()` should be nil so that user can not call one of its methods, such as `frm:size()` which crashes the program.

In the above C++ code for handling the close event, `wb1` and current frame has the same memory address. *Now to my understanding* all I need to do is search the global table for the userdata type `Frame` and compare the memory addresses so that I know I am choosing the right frame and then set it to nil.

However,  `Frame* wb2=(Frame*)lua_touserdata(glbLuaState,-1);` returns a completely different address from `wb1`, therefore I cannot know which variable of type frame I am referring to.

To my understanding `wb2` has a different memory address possibly due to 3 scenarios:

1) `frm` is a full userdata

2) frm is inside global lua table, therefore has a different address (although this doesnt make sense to me as I pushed the address of Frame in C++).

3) I am thinking completely in the wrong way or cant see something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now to my understanding all I need to do is search the global table for the userdata type Frame and compare the memory addresses so that I know I am choosing the right frame and then set it to nil.

Your understanding is wrong.

First, you did not return userdata to Lua. You returned *light* userdata. That's different. The `lua_type` of light userdata is `LUA_TLIGHTUSERDATA`.

Second, even if you fixed that problem, you're not iterating through tables *inside* the global table. So something as simple as this would confound you:

```
global_var = {}
global_var.frame = Frame.new()
```

Lua code should be able to store its data wherever it wants. And if it wants to store some userdata in a table, who are you to say no?

Third, even if you iterated through every table accessible globally *recursively* (with protection from infinite loops), that *wouldn't stop this*:

```
local frm = Frame.new()

function GlobalFunc(...)
    frm:Stuff();
end
```

Because Lua has proper lexical scoping, `GlobalFunc` will store a reference to the `frm` local *internally*. And since `frm` is a `local` variable, you cannot get at it just from iterating through globals.

Generally speaking, if you give a value to Lua, it now *owns that value*. It can do whatever it wants, and it's generally considered rude to break this contract.

Though it's not impossible. The way to handle it is by using an *actual* userdata rather than light userdata. Each regular userdata is an object, a full allocation of memory. Inside that allocation you would store the `Frame` pointer. When it comes time for that `Frame` to be destroyed, all you have to do is set the `Frame` pointer inside the userdata to NULL.

Conceptually, it's like this in C++:

```
struct FramePtr
{
    Frame *ptr;
};
```

Lua would be passing around a single allocation of `FramePtr`. So if you set that allocation's `FramePtr` to NULL, everyone sees it. No iterating through global tables or somesuch.

Of course, accessing the `Frame` from a `FramePtr` requires an extra indirection. However, by using full userdata instead of light userdata, you can *also* attach a proper metatable to it (light userdata doesn't get per-object metatables; every light userdata shares the same metatable).

Comment: I appreciate your comments and examples on the search of global table. I can now see why it is not a good idea to prefer that. However, I am not sure if I am on the same page for the `FrmPtr`. Is there an example that I can look at?

Comment: I am following the rationale adopted by wxLua, such as not destroying the frame but hiding it. So far it works well but I am still interested in the way of making the variable value `nil` in Lua. How about `memset(&frm, 0, sizeof(frm)`, would you recommend using it?

Comment: @macroland: "*I am still interested in the way of making the variable value nil in Lua*" You can be interested in it all you like; that won't change the fact that you *cannot do it*. There will always be some place where Lua could hide a value from you. And what is this `frm` that you are wanting to `memset`?